# contentDocument does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use this function to add the following html code:

```
    function generateAlbumSelect() {
        alert("test");
        var html="";
        html+="<select id='album_select' style='color:red; font-family:calibri; align:middle; width:430px; height:350px;text-align:center; padding: 10px; font-size: 1.4em; line-height: 1; border: 0; ' onchange='parent.generateTrackSelect(this.selectedIndex);' size=" + albums.length + ">";
        for(var i=0;i<albums.length;i++){
            html+="<option>";
            html+= albums[i].title;
            html+="</option>";
        }
        html+="</select>"

        with(document.getElementById('albums_list_frame').contentDocument){
              open();
              write(html);
              close();
            }


    }
```

To this block - however for some reason it does not work, however the alert("test"); does execute.

```
   <body onload = "generateAlbumSelect();">
<form name = 'main'>
    <div id="albums_list_frame" class = "panel_top">
        <h2>Album Listing</h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: And where is the iFrame, and using `with` should be avoided. This is either really complicated, or you have no idea what you're doing ?

Comment: @adeneo I am pretty new to HTML, do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Nope, not really. `contentDocument` is the document of an iFrame, and `with` is something that I've probably seen used maybe a handful times, so I really have no idea what you're trying to do ?

Comment: @adeneo Im trying to add this code -  var html="";
        html+="<select id='album_select' style='color:red; font-family:calibri; align:middle; width:430px; height:350px;text-align:center; padding: 10px; font-size: 1.4em; line-height: 1; border: 0; ' onchange='parent.generateTrackSelect(this.selectedIndex);' size=" + albums.length + ">";
        for(var i=0;i<albums.length;i++){
            html+="<option>";
            html+= albums[i].title;
            html+="</option>";
        }
        html+="</select>"

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest using jQuery; it'd look something like this:

```
function generateAlbumSelect(albums) 
{
    var html = $('<select>') 
                .css({
                        'color':'red', 
                        'font-family':'calibri', 
                        'align':'middle', 
                        'width':'430px', 
                        'height':'350px', 
                        'text-align':'center', 
                        'padding': '10px', 
                        'font-size': '1.4em', 
                        'line-height': '1', 
                        'border': '0'
                    })
                .on('change', function(){
                        generateTrackSelect(this.selectedIndex); // ??
                    });
    $.each(albums, function(idx, val){
        html.append($('<option>').text(val.title));
    })

    $('#albums_list_frame').append(html);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var albums = [{title:'title1'}, {title: 'title2'}];
    generateAlbumSelect(albums);
})
```

A few other remarks:

- The css styling on the select doesn't make sense for the most part.
- You seem to have originally wanted to use an iframe, but you can't make a form around an iframe, an iframe has content from an other page.
- jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/3s32G/